# I want to implement Rerouting in my navigation application which uses Google directions API

Tags: google-maps, routes, navigation

I want to build a navigation application.I created it using Google maps directions APi. The issue I face is re-routing.

How can I find the person deviated from the route, I saw a lot where everyone says 
'PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath 
but I don't understand the way it responds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the application that you try to develop might be against Google Maps APIs Terms of Service. Have a look at section 10.4 c (iii) of ToS:

> **No navigation.** You will not use the Service or Content for or in connection with (a) real-time navigation or route guidance; or (b) automatic or autonomous vehicle control.

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?#section_10_4

Comment: Uber is using Google service for Navigation and route guidance right??,Then how is it possible. If so what we need to do to get such feature,if paid how much?steps? please guide me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Uber is Premium plan customer and they likely have an agreement with Google. I don't know how much the Premium license costs. You can always ask it here: https://developers.google.com/maps/contact-sales/